# bootstrap tags input with typeahead throws (str || "").replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, flask, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

in my last question it turned out that typeahead.js was probably updated [typeahead autocomplete suggestion with ajax doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942769/typeahead-autocomplete-suggestion-with-ajax-doesnt-work). on [bootstrap tags input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) there are some examples, so based on some code from my first question and examples I came out with code below.
When I type for example `s` I get autosuggestion with dropdown `Sandra` but when I click on it I get this error every time: 
`Uncaught TypeError: (str || "").replace is not a function`

test.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" >

<script src="../static/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="../static/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>


<script>
var citynames = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
      url: '/test/?query=*',
      wildcard: '*',
      filter: function(x) {
            return $.map(x, function(item) {
                console.log(item) //["Sandra"]
                return {name: item};
            });
        },
    },
});
citynames.initialize();

$('input').tagsinput({
  itemValue: 'name',
  typeaheadjs: {
    name: 'citynames',
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: citynames.ttAdapter()
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('test.html')

@app.route('/test/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    names = ["John","Jane", "Sandra", "Xerox"]
    query = request.args.get('query')
    return jsonify(options=[name for name in names if query.lower() in name.lower()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by doing this:

```
var citynames = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
      url: '/test/?query=*',
      wildcard: '*',
      filter: function(list) {
          var arr = list.options
          var test = []
          for (var i =0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            test.push(arr[i])
          }
          list = test
          return $.map(list, function(item) {
                console.log(item)
                return {name: item};
            });
        },
    },
});
citynames.initialize();
```

it's probably not the best way :D but it worked

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar by changing loading order from:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap','ui.bootstrap']).controller(...
```

to:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap','mgcrea.ngStrap']).controller(...
```

Good luck!